# C# ComboBox disable highlighting

Tags: c#, combobox, highlighting

I have custom ComboBox, where `DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown;`.DropDown style is set because I want to set the Text property of the ComboBox to something outside the list of values. Everything works good, except that ComboBox is highlighting the text when it's left and when I click on the combobox editing is avaible. How can I cope with this?
To illustrate:

[image]

First Picture is where everything looks good, second is the highlight situation, third editing is on.

Comment: Could it be that you still have focus on the combo-box? Did you try clicking on other controls and verifying it still does the highlighting. If the combo box has the focus, then highlighting will be there. Or are you trying to disable editing?

Comment: Yes, combo-box still have the focus, when the OnLeave event occur, then the highlighting dissapears. But it should dissapear when the dropdown is hided.

Comment: It is just a screenshot, doesn't help us help you.  There's a bug in the code that nobody can see.  You can diagnose it by overriding OnHandleCreated() and setting a breakpoint on it.  Second time it fires you'll get the Wall of Blue.  The call stack tells the tale.

Answer (score 12):

Try un-selecting the text *after* the DropDown closes:

```
void comboBox1_DropDownClosed(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { comboBox1.Select(0, 0); }));
}
```

Comment: Yes, thank you, I had not thought about it. This eliminated highlighting when dropdown is hidden. The editable problem is still here.

Comment: @user1816806 Not sure I know what the "editable problem" is.  Can you expand on that?

Comment: When I click on the combobox, the vertical editing line shows as on the third presented picture. I cant remove or edit the text, because I blocked it in the custom combobox logic, but the line is still present.

Comment: @user1816806 You want to hide the caret in the TextBox?  I'm guessing you would have to find the TextBox handle inside the ComboBox control and pinvoke the HideCaret function.  If the end user can type inside the box, they need to see the Caret.  Don't hide it from them.

Comment: @LarsTech Do you know why it doesn't work when comboBox1.Select(0, 0); is put by itself without BeginInvoke? Basically that's code handling the selection, isn't it? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, exactly I want to hide the caret. Getting the TextBox handle might be complicated,but I will try to do it this way.Thanks a lot.

Comment: @HakuKalay The code that highlights the text comes after the DropDownClosed event happens, so the selection gets reset to the full highlight.  BeginInvoke is a way of running your code after the event, so then it undoes that action.

Comment: @LarsTech You mentioned in a previous comment that to hide the Caret one would need to get the TextBox handle inside the ComboBox control.  Any chance you would know how to get that?  I can use HideCaret on a normal TextBox and it works.  But using it on a ComboBox does nothing and I'm not sure how to get the TextBox handle from a ComboBox like you suggested?

Comment: @Calcolat See if this answer helps you: [Use of NativeWindow for ComboBox causes exception in Dispose-method](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12977295/719186)

Comment: @LarsTech That's awesome.  Using your SendMessageCb example I could get the textbox handle, as well as the other combobox handles,  which was cool.  Thanks for taking the time to respond to a comment on an old question.  I can't accept this as an answer, so I've gone ahead and upvoted both your answers instead.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Tricky problem to solve. It seems to be from the `Resize` event. There are a lot of solutions that do something similar to this, but none that I've seen worked for me until I tried this. (This is a solution that does not require inheritance from `ComboBox`; inheriting is probably a much more straight forward solution, but requires you to always use your inherited class and never the actual `ComboBox` class.)

```
comboBox.Resize += (s, e) => {
   if (!comboBox.IsHandleCreated)
      return;  // avoid possible exception

   comboBox.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => comboBox.SelectionLength = 0));
};
```

Set the selection length to zero to get rid of the highlight, but when? Other examples do it in other places, but the problem seems to be specifically caused by `Resize`, so doing it after `Resize` fixes it consistently, at least for me. (Can still see it flicker when you resize the window though, but it always ends up ok.)

`BeginInvoke` ensures that it happens sufficiently after `Resize` to work, and the check for `IsHandleCreated` prevents it from being called before the handle is created, in which case `BeginInvoke` would throw an exception.

This slightly more complex version includes some checks to prevent a focused control from losing highlight, since it actually should have it. It also doesn't fire if the parent doesn't exist yet, or if the parent does not have an active control yet, both signs that things are too early.

```
comboBox.Resize += (s, e) => {
   if (!comboBox.IsHandleCreated)
      return;

   comboBox.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => {
      var parent = comboBox.FindForm();
      if (parent == null)
         return;

      if (parent.ActiveControl == null)
         return;

      if (parent.ActiveControl == comboBox)
         return;

      comboBox.SelectionLength = 0;
   }));
};
```

I tried to make a version that would 'preserve' the selection length rather than always set it to zero, but I couldn't get it to synchronize properly. Many `Resize` events can fire before the `BeginInvoke` delegates start to fire, so the preserved value will always be overwritten by the broken one. I tried saving them all in a `Queue` or `Stack`, but in both cases, I was unable to reverse the ordering (not really sure why, since that makes no sense).

Comment: The RESIZE event!!?? That's mental! What were M$ thinking? Thanks for the information, it helped me.

Answer (score 4):

If you are referring to disabling the highlighting and editing, then you might want to consider setting the `DropdownStyle` property to `DropdownList`.

```
yourComboBox.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
```

Comment: I know about the `DropdownList` but it casues another problem, that I mentioned "set the Text property of the ComboBox to something outside the list of values"

Answer (score 4):

To solve the same I have tried almost EVERYTHING:

- setting the `DropdownStyle` property to `DropdownList`
- `this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { comboBox1.Select(0, 0); }));`
- `combobox1.SelectionLength = 0;`
- changing `comboBox.TabIndex`
- Not tried `SendKeys.Send("{ESC}");` because it is not a reliable solution

Nothing helped.
The only stable and working solution was to move a focus on another Label control:

```
    label.Focus();
```

You could also hide that label.

Answer (score 1):

I know this post is old but recently I have the same problem with combobox.

**Situation :** I have an editable combobox which propose complete words when user write some letters.

But when I want to type a letter, combobox auto highlight the text and the next letter auto replace the previous.

**Solution :** I use a textbox to avoid any highlight like that:

```
<ComboBox IsTextSearchEnabled="False" IsEditable="True" x:Name="CMB_ClientName"/>
<TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=CMB_ClientName, Path=Text}" TextChanged="ComboBoxChange" x:Name="TXT_ClientName"/>
```

And I generate the textbox TextChanged event :

```
private void ComboBoxChange(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Clear ComboBox items
        CMB_ClientName.Items.Clear();
        //Auto Open DropDownList
        CMB_ClientName.IsDropDownOpen = true;

        //Get data from database (use entity framework 6.x)
        dbEntity.Client.Load();

        //Attribute Data to variable
        var clients = dbEntity.Client.Local;


        foreach (Client client in clients)
        {
            //If data begin with the texbox text, the data is add to the combobox items list.
            if (client.Nom.ToLower().StartsWith(TXT_NomClient.Text.ToLower()))
            {
                CMB_ClientName.Items.Add(client.Nom);
            }
        }
    }
```

I know this solution isn't realy beautifull, but it is for me the easiest solution to avoid highlight text and all the solutions in this post don't work for me.

I hope this solution will be helpfull, thanks for reading.

Math.

Ps: My apologies, my English is not very good. I hope you will understand me correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing worked for me ( I want the form to load with no highlighting in any combobox) until I set the combobox property TabStop to false. This meant that one of my buttons took the tab highlight which I didn't like so I set them all to false for start up and adjusted them programatically as needed.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please review: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but my solution is similar to that of the others, but relies on the Form.ResizeEnd event. In its event handler, I iterate through the ComboBoxes and set ComboBox.SelectionLength to 0.

```
private void Form_ResizeEnd(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach(ComboBox comboBox in parentControl.Controls.OfType<ComboBox>
    {
        comboBox.SelectionLength = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

1. Set DrawMode to OwnerDrawFixed
2. Set cbxSubsystems.DrawItem event to the function below

```
private void cbxSubsystems_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    Color BgClr;
    Color TxClr;

    if( (e.State & DrawItemState.ComboBoxEdit) == DrawItemState.ComboBoxEdit )
    {
        // Do not highlight main display
        BgClr = cbxSubsystems.BackColor;
        TxClr = cbxSubsystems.ForeColor;
    }
    else
    {
        BgClr = e.BackColor;
        TxClr = e.ForeColor;
    }

    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(BgClr), e.Bounds);

    TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, cbxSubsystems.Items[e.Index].ToString(), e.Font, e.Bounds,
        TxClr, BgClr, TextFormatFlags.Left | TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter );
}
```